# Laravel: Can a second user change $request values, while first one's request is still under progress?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I was wondering if the $request instance is separate for each user or are they shared? For example, if its values are changed in nested functions, can a second user's request mess with the result of the first one? Does it behave like global variables or is it safe to use it this way?

I hope I am clear enough, if not please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: two users do not share the same session if that is what you are asking. this isn't the best place to ask general questions like this, just a warning, some people will tear you apart

Comment: The Laravel Request class is only available for the current request. Therefore can't be shared across users.

Comment: Thanks and Noted @GiovanniS. And thanks @ dangermark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Users do not share a session or a request.

Each request is treated individually, and two requests at once, can go through the same routes/controllers etc and contain completely different data without issue.

`$request` is an instance of the `Request` class and every request has its own instance of this; this means calls or changes to `$request` in the lifecycle of that request are isolated to that single request.